# th:field Not grabbing data from th:value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Ok, so, basically I have to use an input with this value in order to sent it to a form post to delete the row I want...

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{id}" value="${customer.id}" />
```

but what happens? Well.. the property `th:field="*{id}"` is not doing its job, as you can see here:

[image: Screenshot]

That number 3 you can see is the submit button, as you see its grabbing the value correctly but doesn't matter what I do, everytime I try to delete something, it wont do, and not, is not the logic because hardcoded the id on html on some dumb input and it worked..

Here is the html code:

```
<form th:action="@{/DeleteCustomer}"
                                th:object="${customersdelete}" method="post">
                                <span th:value="${customer.id}"></span>

                                <span th:field="*{id}" value="${customer.id}"></span>

                                <input type="text" 
                                th:field="*{id}" value="${customer.id}" />

<!--                                <input type="text" th:value="${customer.id}" th:field="*{id}" /> -->

                                <input
                                    type="submit" name="btnInsert" class="btn btn-primary"
                                    value="Delete" th:value="${customer.id}" />
                            </form>
```

CONTROLLER

```
@PostMapping("/DeleteCustomer")
    public ModelAndView DeletDis(@ModelAttribute("customersdelete") Customers Customers) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        System.err.println("ID =" + Customers.getId());
        customersService.removeCustomer(Customers.getId());
        customersService.listAllCustomers();
        mav.setViewName("redirect:/" + MAIN_VIEW);
        return mav;

    }
```

ERROR:

```
ID =0
Hibernate: select customers0_.id as id1_0_0_, customers0_.address as address2_0_0_, customers0_.course as course3_0_0_, customers0_.firstname as firstnam4_0_0_, customers0_.lastname as lastname5_0_0_ from customers customers0_ where customers0_.id=?
2018-02-13 11:17:25.924  INFO 10812 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.p.s.component.RequestTimeInterceptor   : --REQUEST URL:'http://localhost:8080/DeleteCustomer'-- TOTAL TIME: '8'ms
2018-02-13 11:17:25.927 ERROR 10812 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class com.project.springinventory.entity.Customers entity with id 0 exists!] with root cause

org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class com.project.springinventory.entity.Customers entity with id 0 exists!
```

Things that i've tried and doesn't worked for me:

```
                            <input type="text" 
                                th:field="*{id}" value="${customer.id}" />



                            <input type="text" 
                                th:field="*{id}" th:value="${customer.id}" />

                    <input type="hidden" 
                                th:field="*{id}" th:value="${customer.id}" />
```

<= displays 0 while id is 4 or something

checked objects, checked everything. I don't know what to do.

What i've saw, if i delete   th:field="*{id}"  the id will load on the input but won't send into the post, tried creating another object just with diferent name in order to avoid clash of data or something and still the same..

```
    <tr th:each="customer:${customers}">
                        <th><span th:value="${customer.id}"></span></th>
                        <th><span th:text="${customer.id}"></span></th>
                        <th><span th:text="${customer.firstname}"></span></th>
                        <th><span th:text="${customer.lastname}"></span></th>
                        <th><span th:text="${customer.course}"></span></th>
                        <th><span th:text="${customer.address}"></span></th>
                        <th>
                            <form th:action="@{/showCustomer}" th:object="${customers}"
                                method="post">
                                <button class="btn btn-warning">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true">Show</span>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                            <form th:action="@{/UpdateCustomer}" th:object="${customers}"
                                method="post">
                                <button class="btn btn-warning">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true">Edit</span>
                                </button>
                            </form>

                            <form th:action="@{/DeleteCustomer}"
                                th:object="${customersdelete}" method="post">
                                <span th:value="${customer.id}"></span>

                                <span th:field="*{id}" value="${customer.id}"></span>

                                <input type="text" 
                                th:field="*{id}" value="${customer.id}" />

<!--                                <input type="text" th:value="${customer.id}" th:field="*{id}" /> -->

                                <input
                                    type="submit" name="btnInsert" class="btn btn-primary"
                                    value="Delete" th:value="${customer.id}" />
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

th:field sets the name, value and id of an input tag. (Overwriting some of the values you've set manually.)

Since your `th:object` is defined as `${customersdelete}`, the expressions `*{id}` means `${customersdelete.id}` -- which is different than what you are trying with 
 `th:value="${customer.id}"`. The expression `th:value="${customer.id}"` is completely ignored.

You should set the id of customersdelete in the controller before the form, and not use `th:value="${customer.id}"`.

Comment: but what if i use the same object customers to it? i tried it but won't work and thats why i've created the other object, what you could suggest to me?